# Read content of tags from other page

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a page with several articles/blogs. I would like to read all the Titles into a list using divs in another page like "check my latest blogs".

I want to read all the div's with a specific class from a specific page and show those title in another page. Initially, I thought to load those tags with PHP, Ajax into a JSON and echo the result. But so far I have no idea how I would do it.

Sounds complicated but I am trying to avoid code maintenance and make the page read and load the Title of the Article from another page automatic.

Yes, WordPress will do the work just fine but I am not a WordPress user.

Comment: Yes Indeed. I am just wondering how I would loop until the end of the file and echo all the Titles?

Comment: It is get the content from the url. You have to pass the url each time

Comment: Why you are waste your time in php code use jquery instead.   jQuery(' h1').each(function(){ jQuery(this).text(); });

Comment: jQuery indeed. However, I am not that good yet with it. In your example how would you point for a url?

Comment: You don't need url.You can put this code on page load event so it will grab the current page title

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple add the page and add the query on that page.All the blog posts are displaying and if you want only the title then remove only the_post();

```
<?php 
    $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); 
    if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<ul>
    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->
</ul>
   <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no post found' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Anand. However, this is not a WP web page. I just need read the Title from the page I have all my blogs and show in the front page. I am not using a database at all.

Comment: jQuery('header > h1.entry-title a').each(function(){
 jQuery(this).html();   
});

Comment: this will also take the post title of a main blog page

Comment: I just found this piece of code. How would I loop until the end and echo the results?

<?php
    function page_title($url) {
        $fp = file_get_contents($url);
        if (!$fp)
            return null;

        $res = preg_match("/<h3>(.*)<\/h3>/siU", $fp, $title_matches);
        if (!$res)
            return null;

        // Clean up title: remove EOL's and excessive whitespace.
        $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $title_matches[1]);
        $title = trim($title);
        return $title;
    }

    print page_title("http://www.somewebpage.com/");
?>